# Changing the properties of elements in Office Ribbon using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

I am a beginner in VBA and Office Ribbon UI. I am using Office 2007 and used Custom UI to develop a Ribbon in PPTM. I have added a set of XML like the one below:

```
<group id="myGroup" label="Hello World" visible="false">
    <labelControl id="lblUsername" label="Your Username: " />
    <labelControl id="lblFullname" label="" />
</group>
```

So, in this `Hello World` tab, I would like to change its visibility to `true` and change the the values of `lblUsername` and `lblFullname`. Currently this has to be done after the previous call by this button:

```
<button id="signin" label="Sign In" image="signin" size="large"
    supertip="Click this button to sign in."
    onAction="ribbon_SignIn" tag="SignIn" />
```

Right now the code in the `ribbon_SignIn` is as follows:

```
Sub ribbon_SignIn()
    SignIn.Show
End Sub
```

This opens the `SignIn` form and gets the Username and Password from the user. After the username and password are validated, everything goes fine, but I am not sure what is the procedure to get the properties of controls `lblUsername` and `lblFullname` to change their values with the signed in user's details.

---

#### Clarification

In the `SignIn` form I have the below code for the <kbd>Sign In</kbd> button.

```
Private Sub btnSignIn_Click()
    ' Authentication Mechanism
    MsgBox "You have successfully signed in!"

    ' Show the Ribbon group.
    ' What am I supposed to do here to make the group visible?
    ' Also how do I change the text of the label?
End Sub
```

So, here what should I put to make the group visible? Also how do I change the text of the label?

---

#### Update #1

When I use the two attributes `getVisible` and `getLabel` in the Custom UI, the add-in itself is not getting displayed. `:(` The code that I used was:

```
<group id="myGroup" label="Hello World" getVisible="VisibleGroup">
    <labelControl id="lblUsername" label="Your Username: " getLabel="lblUsername" />
    <labelControl id="lblFullname" label="" getLabel="lblFullname" />
</group>
```

If I remove those two attributes, Weird. BTW, I am using **Office 2007**.

Comment: hmmm haven't tried this before let me see if I can figure it out. +1 for interesting Q.

Comment: Nothing worked. But I accepted the answer for the effort you have put in and upvoted both. :) That's the best I was able to do!

Comment: If you can show your full xml perhaps I can figure out how to fix it for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple, functional example. I substitute simple `InputBox` prompts instead of trying to recreate your UserForm code, but the general principal should still apply.

I create public variables for username and fullname and bAuthenticated (have your form assign to these variables, or reference the form directly).  Set `bAuthenticated = True` once you have authenticated the user.

Use the `getLabel` callback and refresh the ribbon.  I create two separate callbacks, one for username, one for fullname, these are `getUserName` and `getFullName`.  I also add the vba for `VisibleGroup` which is called from the `getVisible` XML property.

**Note** when making changes to your VBA you will likely have to save, close & re-open the file, because making these changes may clear all public variables, including the variable which represents the ribbon itself. This is why you might be getting errors from the `RefreshRibbon` procedure.

Your xml might look like this.

**Updated to include the getVisible callback**

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="RibbonOnLoad">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false" >
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="Custom Tab">
                      <group id="myGroup" label="Hello World" getVisible="VisibleGroup" >
                          <labelControl id="lblUsername" getLabel="getUserName" />
                          <labelControl id="lblFullname" getLabel="getFullName" />
                      </group>
                      <group id="mySignin" label="SignIn" visible="true" >
                          <button id="signin" label="Sign In" size="large"
                              supertip="Click this button to sign in."
                              onAction="ribbon_SignIn" tag="SignIn" />
                      </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

**Note:** I have set the visible property of *myGroup* to `True` so that I could more easily test this. You can use the `getVisible` callback similarly, if you need to change this property at run-time.

And then the callbacks in VBA module will look more or less like:

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Rib As IRibbonUI
Public xmlID As String
Public username As String
Public fullName As String
Public bAuthenticated As Boolean

'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    'MsgBox "onLoad"
    Set Rib = ribbon
End Sub

Sub ribbon_SignIn(control As IRibbonControl)

    username = InputBox("enter your username", "Your username?")
    fullName = InputBox("enter your full name", "Your full name?")

    'Authenticate
    bAuthenticated = True

    VisibleGroup control, bAuthenticated
End Sub
Sub VisibleGroup(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = bAuthenticated
    Call RefreshRibbon("myGroup")
End Sub
Sub getUserName(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = username
    Call RefreshRibbon(control.id)
End Sub
Sub getFullName(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = fullName
    Call RefreshRibbon(control.id)
End Sub
Sub RefreshRibbon(id As String)
    xmlID = id
    'MsgBox "Refreshing ribbon for " & Id, vbInformation
    If Rib Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error, Save/Restart your Presentation"
    Else
        Rib.Invalidate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to use the `getVisible` property of the Group control and a boolean to determine whether the user has authenticated successfully or not, then refresh the ribbon.

Comment: What's the `xmlID`? How does it get associated with it? I am getting just errors, like undefined.

Comment: OK. If you have trouble with it, let me know and update your Q to include the full CustomXML you are using so I can see how it is set up.

Comment: When I use the two attributes `getVisible` and `getLabel` in the Custom UI, the add-in itself is not getting displayed. `:(` If I remove both of them, it works. Weird. BTW, I am using Office 2007. What should I do?

Comment: Can you include your full XML?

Answer (score 4):

You can use something called the `getLabel` property in your xml.

e.g.

```
getLabel = "GetLabelMacro"
```

Now in your GetLabelMacro you can put in code as

```
Sub GetLabelMacro(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
    if control.id = "MyLabel" then
        label = "New Label"
    end if
End Sub
```

You can modify this sample code for your purposes. More info on the syntax of getLabel can be found by googling about the getLabel callback.

Comment: This should work in VBA as any other callback function.

Comment: Actually @DavidZemen's answer here describes how this can be used but is much more detailed (am typing from a mobile device so my answer would be a bit too brief)

Comment: Quick and dirty way should be to update a global Boolean variable with your Macro, and then that variable should be used in the callback function `label = GlobalVariableBoolean`. Then you will need to refresh the ribbon using the example provided by David.

Comment: Okay, will try that @hnk, isn't there any other way other than "refreshing" the XML?

Comment: Not too sure about that. Try updating the global variable, and see what happens. I don't know if the ribbon autorefreshes using some events or on 'calculate' of the spredsheet.

Comment: No you will have to refresh the ribbon.

Comment: Okay sure then, @DavidZemens!

Comment: I defer to David's view on that. I don't know any documented way of making the ribbon update itself otherwise either.

Comment: When I use the two attributes `getVisible` and `getLabel` in the Custom UI, the add-in itself is not getting displayed. `:(` If I remove both of them, it works. Weird. BTW, I am using **Office 2007**. What should I do?

Comment: Hi, I just tried a piece of code with getLabel, it certainly works when a spreadsheet opens. Check out the example sheet by Ron De Bruin (the original site is down but the wayback archive exists) https://web.archive.org/web/20121013175458/http://www.rondebruin.nl/dynamic.htm   You will still need to refresh it separately.