# Changing ActiveMacro's Ribbon Label in VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, events, label, ribbon

I have a continuous, event-triggered macro that can be turned "off" and "on" by clicking its button on the ribbon. Essentially it keeps a count of how many cells are altered in a certain column. The problem is that sometimes I forget whether I have started the macro or not, and then it restarts the count. I'm wondering whether it's possible to alter the macro's label on the ribbon from within the macro. So when it is on, the text could read "ON", and when it's off, it could say "OFF." Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612706/changing-the-properties-of-elements-in-office-ribbon-using-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add at the beginning of the macro code

```
application.StatusBar="ON"
```

and have the statusbar at the bottom right of your excel window say "ON" till another similar statement

```
application.StatusBar=false
```

to be placed right before the `End Sub` statement and reset the statusbar to its default functioning.

this solution has the drawback that you're not getting possible helping info from the status bar till the macro ends

Comment: That worked for me, thanks. I don't pay mind to the status bar otherwise, so it does the job.